# C++ Use String Variable in Value - CIM Provider

Tags: c++

I am creating a CIM provider in which my schema.mof file looks like this:

```
class CIM_pvtv 
{ 
[Key] String name; 
String text; 
};
```

I then run omigen which creates all the files and so on.
I am having trouble understanding the C++ in pvtv_Class_Provider.cpp file. Here is the simple code:

```
29 void pvtv_Class_Provider::EnumerateInstances(
30     Context& context,
31     const String& nameSpace,
32     const PropertySet& propertySet,
33     bool keysOnly,
34     const MI_Filter* filter)
35 {
36         pvtv_Class yup;
37
38         std::string sometext;
39         sometext = "hi";
40
41         yup.name_value("Jim");
42         yup.text_value(sometext);
43
44         context.Post(yup);
45         context.Post(MI_RESULT_OK);
46 }
```

I then get this when I run make:

```
 sudo make
g++ -c -g -fPIC -Wall -fvisibility=hidden -fno-strict-aliasing -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600         -D_BSD_SOURCE -I///opt/omi/include pvtv_Class_Provider.cpp -o pvtv_Class_Provider.o
pvtv_Class_Provider.cpp: In member function void mi::pvtv_Class_Provider::EnumerateInstances(mi::Context&, const mi::String&, const mi::PropertySet&, bool, const MI_Filter*):
pvtv_Class_Provider.cpp:42: error: no matching function for call to âmi::pvtv_Class::text_value(std::string&)
pvtv.h:368: note: candidates are: const mi::String& mi::pvtv_Class::text_value() const
pvtv.h:374: note:                 void mi::pvtv_Class::text_value(const mi::String&)
make: *** [pvtv_Class_Provider.o] Error 1
```

The problem I am having is using a varible "sometext" in yup.text_value(). It works fine if I assign it a value in quotes like this yup.text_value("hello"), but for some reason I can't use a string variable in it. What am I doing wrong? 
Thank You

Comment: the function takes a `const mi::String &` and not a `std::string` it appears that string literals are implicitly convertible to it, but `std::string` is not. You can confirm this by making it `yup.text_value(sometext.c_str());` instead

Comment: I got it to work just now, but I don't really understand why. I used yup.text_value(sometext.data());. I think that's basically what you said, but I don't quite understand .data() vs .c_str(). Thank You for the response!

Comment: `.data()` is not guaranteed to be 0-terminated and could lead to a buffer-overflow.

Comment: nvm, `.data()` is guaranteed to be null-terminated since C++-11, so only be aware if you are using an older C++ standard